# Another word for cute or adorable used as diminutive, sarcasm or condescension

Tags: single-word-requests, offensive-language

I'm looking for a word that one could use by itself as one would use "cute" or "adorable" in a sarcastic, emasculating manner.

Comment: I'm writing a paper about weightlifting and wanted to touch on the fact that many of my good friends have commented over the years on my "cute little girl calves." We're meat-heads, insulting each other is what we do.

Comment: [Already answered then](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16115_4732).

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. While "...esoteric rude words to use to commit verbal violence upon one another" is the topic, my aim is to find a succinct way of summarizing - a word that can stand without context - in order to avoid a more laborious, wordy use of "cute."

Comment: I dunno, using words *androjocular-emasculatrically* seems pretty close to what you want.

Comment: Surely **'cute'** already fits your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of 'twee' might be evirating

**[Twee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twee)**: affectedly or excessively dainty, delicate, cute, or quaint

Answer (score 3):

The term **[precious](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/precious)** is often used in an ironic and derogatory manner

> Affectedly dainty or overrefined: *precious mannerisms*.

Answer (score 2):

How about *darling*.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

Comsider *mignon* and *petite*.

> [**mignon**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mignon): small and pretty; delicately pretty
>
> [**petite**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/petite) : *(of or characteristic of a woman)* small, delicate, and dainty: *petite calves*

Answer (score 1):

How about *girly-man*? As in Hans, who might comment on Franz's *girly-man* calves? Of course I refer to Hans and Franz (We are here to pump you up!) of SNL.

Answer (score 1):

I think *pretty* used for a boy/man or *handsome* used for a girl/woman.

Describing anyone as [delicate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delicate) is probably done so sarcastically.  I would throw in *elegant* too.

And then unless it is a dad talking about his daughter add in *treasure*, *jewel*, *gem*, *little diamond*.

> She is just such a delicate girl, you must be so proud.
>
> How glorious she is with the little bows in her hair.
>
> He is so little.  Look how pretty he is.
>
> **And in your specific case:**  Look at those delicate little calves on his gem of a body.  His legs are so elegant, he is so pretty.

Answer (score 1):

"Sissy" or "Sissy-Boy" are the terms that jump to mind, since you don't seem to be worried about being PC.

Answer (score 1):

*Diddy* is a version of the word 'little' which is meant to sound like a baby is saying it, or an adult is saying it to a baby in a  'baby voice'.

> Did you hurt your diddy little calves?

could be said sarcastically. The expression *lickle*, *ickle* or *ickle-wickle* could be used in a similar way. There is also a word *Diddums* which means 'little one', is used to refer to a baby, and is almost only ever used sarcastically:

> Did you hurt your ickle-wickle calves? Aah, Diddums!